# Cannot see "conver role in this Farm" in Central Admin of WFE server after Upgrade SharePoint 2016

Tags: central-administration, upgrade, front-end

I installed sharepoint 2016 but in Central Admin, System setting
 I cannot see option “Convert role in this Farm”. So I recently applied January 2018 CU to my environment which consists of 1 WFE and 1 APP and 1 search server. After running the upgrade and restart the servers. I ran the PS Config through UI and it was successful. When I checked the upgrade status  on server, all of them were succeded.

The problem is that the central admin in WFE wasn’t update. When I browsed Central admin in chrome I cannot see the option “ Convert Server role in this farm”. But after I ran the PS Config through UI and finished it automatically open central admin through Internet Explorer and the option exist.

The option exists in both App and Search servers. If I restart WFE server I should run again PS Config through UI to see the option through Internet Explorer.

I want to change WFE role to custom in order to start Microsoft SharePoint foundation WF timer service. Because sometimes the workflow has error
Error processing XML. Your license file is incomplete or corrupt. Please contact Nintex support for a new license file. Error

I install license in WFE. After 3 or 4 days I should restart server and change role to WFE and again change it to custom and start Microsoft SharePoint foundation WF timer service.
How can I resolve it?

Thanks for your time and consideration.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

Thanks for your reply.
I configure the central admin on WFE server and  the url of central admin is http://wsfeds-srv-02. 
also, I can access the Central admin url through other servers such as search and application servers. When I run the IE Browser as Administrator in WFE server, I cannot see "Convert role in this farm" in Central Admin. but when I Run the IE Browser in others servers and even my computer I can see option.

the main problem is that I need to execute Workflow in Nintex. the Workflow has a Query xml action. workflow run with error 
Error processing XML. Your license file is incomplete or corrupt. Please contact Nintex support for a new license file.
Nintex License is installed in WFE server. In order to resolve this problem, I need to use "Convert Server role in this Farm" option and change WFE role to custom. 
So I recently applied January 2018 CU to see "Convert role in this farm" in Central Admin.
Central admin, system setting, manage services on server. I start "Microsoft Sharepoint foundation Workflow timer service"

After exactly  3 days workflow run with error Error processing XML. and I have to restart WFE server and run sharepoint wizard. then Start workflow timer service.

I want to run workflow without error.I'm not sure that the problem is for upgrade or something else?
Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: there is confusion in your question....How many central admin web sites you have? did you configure the Central admin on App server only? On WFE, when you open the central admin...what is the URL of it? is it contain app server url or WFE url?

Answer (score 1):

One of the root causes of missing the **"[Convert Server role in this Farm](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/sharepoint-2016-convert-server-role/)"** option is the current login account doesn't have sufficient permission to perform this action.

**So you should make sure that the current login account has the following permission:**

- A member of the Farm administrator group.
- A Local administrator on the WFE server.
- Run the IE Browser as Administrator.

> For more details please, check **[SharePoint 2016 Convert Server Role in this farm](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/sharepoint-2016-convert-server-role/)**

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I check permission. but the current login account is both a member of  Farm administrator group and a local administrator of WFE. do you have any other solution?
How can I’m sure that upgrade successful. Because exactly after 3 days. Workflow run with error processing XML. Your license file is incomplete or corrupt. Please contact Nintex. and I have to change role to custom and start workflow timer service.

Answer (score -1):

According to Nintex comunity 
https://community.nintex.com/thread/6033

error "Your license file is incomplete or corrupt" happens when there is a spike in CPU usage.

Thanks.